Probability more than 3 or more pairs of adjacent people look at each other.
I have some old interview questions I've been sitting and stewing on. One of them I'm having trouble with goes as so:

You have 10 people sitting around a table. Everyone either turns left or right with equal chance to look at the person adjacent to them. What is the probability that you have 3 or more pairs of people looking at each other.

I might be missing some of the details provided, but I'm pretty sure it is still a well defined problem. Also, I don't have the most formal math background but I took a very intro Probability Theory class. Here is how I've been attempting:
Let $X$ be a random variable denoting the number of pairs of people looking at each other. So $X$ takes on values $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.
If we label the people $0, 1, 2, \dots , 9$ then we can see all possible 10 pairs are $(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8), (8,9), (9,0)$.
So we want to calculate $P(X\geq3)$. I first wanted to try calculating $P(X\geq1)$ which I found some issues with my reasoning but don't know how to solve. I put:
$P(X\geq1)=P($pair 1 right person turns left$)P($pair 1 left person turns left$) + P($pair 2 right person turns left$)P($pair 2 left person turns left$)+\cdots+P($pair 10 right person turns left$)P($pair 10 left person turns left$)=10P($right person turns left$)P($left person turns left$)=10\frac12\frac12=\frac52$ which violates the requirement that a probability measure is less than or equal to 1.
Pretty sure $P(X\geq1)=1-\frac{1}{2^9}$ as $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)$ and $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2^9}$ because in order to have no pairs looking at each other everyone must be looking left or right so, the two ways is everyone looking at one direction or another: $2(\frac{1}{2^{10}})=\frac{1}{2^9}$ or, equivalently, let the first person go whichever direction they want and find the probability of everyone following which is $\frac{1}{2^9}$. However, I don't think I can extend this reasoning as far easily.
I tried thinking of how to solve for $P(X=0)$, $P(X=1)$, $P(X=2)$, and then do $P(X\geq3)=1 - (P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2))$, but for finding $P(X=1)$ I've had trouble ensuring that my probability only accounts for exactly one pair and doesn't let other pairs form. There are just so many different ways where the same pair of people are looking at each other but other people are looking in different directions but not making pairs but then also so many ways to accidentally account for additional pairs.
Also for the above work finding $P(X\geq1)$, I know choosing 10 is most likely the culprit, I just thought that we'd want to consider the possibility of each pair looking at each other but since there is overlapping this is probably what causes it to not work. However choosing 5 (the maximum number of pairs possible at once) has the same issue and doesn't make as much sense to me since we aren't giving every pair a chance at existing, not sure what else to consider and then how to continue that reasoning for $P(X\geq2)$ and $P(X\geq3)$.

Hint: Count the sequences themselves. If you let them look L or R, what does it mean for exactly 1 pair to look at each other?

@CalvinLin Ahhh I think I see what you are alluding to. The number of times we flip from listing L's to R's or visa versa, denoted F, means that $\lfloor\frac{F+1}{2}\rfloor$ is the number of pairs (pretty sure, or I might be slightly off), and I still need to figure out what that means exactly. I'll check later in case this is not it but otherwise will keep going with it. Thank you!

@CalvinLin I got it, that was it! Thank you very much.
In case others come across this, the key was doing 10 choose x times $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ (where x is the number of flips needed for a certain number of pairs, and there may be multiple values of x for a certain number of pairs). Then the multiplying by $\frac{1}{2^{10}}=\frac{1}{2^{x}}\frac{1}{2^{10-x}}$ makes the x flips and the 10-x continuing whatever the sequence was on.
Anyways my results doing that for $P(X=1)$ , $P(X=2)$ , $P(X=3)$ , $P(X=4)$ , satisfied $1-P(X=0)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)$ so I'll assume that is correct.

Perfect. Note that there are not multiple values of $x$ for a certain number of pairs. To get $k$ people looking at each other, along the circle there must be exactly $2k$ flips. $\quad$ Can you post that as an answer?
